# How to use LIKE operator in sql query that returns data that didn't match exactly the value but has a few words in it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a book titled "Web Developer", "Web Designer" and I want a query that will return both book when I searched anything that's has "web" word in it for example "Web Consultant". But the problem is when I query like this it's not returning any data

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `title` LIKE '%Web Consultant%';
```

but I know changing the like value to '%web%' will return all data with "web" world in it. But my problem is what if the user add some words after the "web" word.

So the question is what is the exact approach or query for doing it, thanks!

Example: the scenario here is what if a user is searching for something that he can't remember the full title but only a word in it. So he will try to search like "web blahblablah" so the goal here is I want to return all books that has a "web" word on their title's

Comment: `SELECT * FROM \`books\` WHERE \`title\` LIKE '%Web Developer%' OR \`title\` LIKE '%Web Designer%';`

Comment: hi sir Nick thanks for the response but i think you misunderstood my question. what i'm telling is i want to return both books entitled  "Web Developer" and "Web Designer" when i searched  "Web Consultant" for some reason.

Comment: You can't return both with a search for *Web Consultant*, because neither of them matches *Web Consultant*. If you need to put multiple items into the same category, add a new column and use it to group them. You can't make up arbitrary matches on words that don't exist. The only way to find both of them is to use `Web%` or `%Web%`. *Web Consultant* doesn't match. You also can't expect a search for *Meat* to work when your data contains *Steak* and *Hamburger*, because there is no match.

Comment: yes i agreed with you on that but what i have seen many web sites that's which i think have done that if i'm not mistaken. for example job posting sites if you search for a job they'll show you some result that is not what exactly you searched but has relation on it.

Comment: I got your point of question, you could use search engine like Apache Solr which could grab entities from mysql and parse column to words collection such as `web` and others, that Solr also parse the input like `Web Consultant` to separate words such as `web` & `consultant` for union mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > what if the user add[s] some words after the "web" word

If you want a list of books whose title contains "web" followed by some unknown word, then you can execute something this:

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `title` REGEXP 'web[[:blank]]+[[:alpha:]]+'
```

Of course, it depends on how you define `word` as to what follows the `+` in the above RE. But I think the point of your question is that you want to exclude books whose title ends with "web" because you know that there must be some word after it. You can look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) for more details on how you can define `word`.

You should keep in mind that you asked to find "web" followed by some unknown word. If you had said you wanted to find the *word* web followed by some unknown word, then the RE would be more complex. You would have to allow the "w" to be either at the beginning of the title or be preceded by a whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks for the informative information's you gave to me. i found the answer
    
      SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `title` REGEXP '[a-z][Web Consultant][a-z];

Comment: @arnoldemzi The pattern `[a-z][Web Consultant][a-z]` is too rough to search even that unrelated titles would be find out.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions to the rescue, though the details vary across implementations. I've been using Oracle lately, but reviewing MySql, if you don't need multi-byte characters, I come up with:

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE title REGEXP 'Web Developer|Web Designer'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

Comment: hi sir Gilbert thanks for the response but i think you misunderstood my question. what i'm telling is i want to return both books entitled "Web Developer" and "Web Designer" when i searched "Web Consultant" for some reason.

Comment: How does this solve the problem using *Web Consultant* as the search phrase (which is what the question asks)?

Comment: the scenario here is what if a user is searching for something that he can't remember the full title but only a word in it. so he well try to search like "web blahblablah" so the goal here is i want to return all books that has a "web" word on there title's

Comment: Reading OP as "I have two books titled 'Web Developer' and "Web Designer' and I want a query that will return both books"  REGEXP 'Web Developer|Web Designer' will find all titles with either of the phrases, including "Bigger Web Developer Tips".  The | is a logical OR for the RE. If you are looking for partly remembered title you can add more terms to the RE, or get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to handle the input before query:

1. Explode the input to an array by blank. PHP for example:

   `$wordArray = explode(' ', 'Web Consultant');`
2. Combine each word into `OR` conditions to a query:

   `SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%Web%' OR title LIKE '%Consultant%';`

This is a simple pattern what search engine does.

In your case, you could also define the first word to `'Web%'`, which makes more accurate for finding a title pattern.